# Saving additional data when checkout is completed on shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm not entirely sure how to go about this so i thought i'd ask here.

### Context

I have a quiz that people take on my site and when the quiz is completed, a product is recommended based on their quiz results. A customer is now able to buy this recommended product.

What i want to do is to be able to save the quiz response to my external database with the order id as a unique id for quick retrieval later. How would i go about this in Shopify?

### Question

- Is there a way i can make a POST request when the checkout button is pressed on the checkout page?
- Would i have to create a custom checkout to get access to that area?

Thank you

Comment: you need to create a custom APP and then store the data from the order thanks page, where you able to get the ID of the order and send a request to the APP proxy URL to save the data to a custom database.

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to save to an external database then you'll need to figure out a way to send data from your Shopify frontend to an external app or API, one that will capture the product data and add it to the DB.

To answer your first question, no, you can not hijack the functionality of the checkout button (unless you do so via Javascript).

As for your second question, I don't know what you mean by 'custom checkout' but I'd say you're probably looking in the wrong area for the solution to this.

Shopify's backend is not able to be edited by the merchant themselves and can only be accessed via its various APIs.

How I would do it if I were you is to create that external app, create an endpoint that accepts the product data / adds to the DB and write code on your Shopify front-end to send the data to that endpoint.

Keep in mind that you won't be able to easily identify the customer to whom the product is recommended to unless they are logged in.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for responding. So i already have the custom app built with the endpoint, it's more capturing the order number from the purchase. The quiz is saved to the db before the product is paid for. Ideally I'd like the quiz to be saved with the order number as one POST request. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you on Shopify Plus? If you're not, your options are limited as you are no able to edit the `checkout.liquid` file without it.

Comment: Yeah i recently noticed this, i'll have a little think - thanks for your help so far!